# BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery

Is there anyway to run queries repeatedly on google BigQuery using a Python Script?

I want to query a dataset using Google BigQuery Platform for a weeks data and I want to this over a year. It is a bit too tedious to query the dataset 52 times. Instead I would prefer to write a Python script(As I know Python).

I hope someone could point me in the right direction regarding this.

Comment: [A quick Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Google%20BigQuery%20Python) reveals that this is possible... It also mentions Python right there on the BigQuery homepage... Not sure what you confusion/question is here?

Comment: cron job + python  code hosted on App Engine? You'll have to be more specific in your question though

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery supplies client libraries for several languages -- see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries -- and in particular for Python, with docs at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/?_ga=1.176926572.834714677.1415848949 (you'll need to follow the hyperlinks to understand the docs).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart gives an example of a command-line program, in either Java or Python, that uses the Google BigQuery API to run a query on one of the available Sample Datasets and display the result.  After imports, and setting a few constants, the Python script boils down to

```
  storage = Storage('bigquery_credentials.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
      # Run oauth2 flow with default arguments.
      credentials = tools.run_flow(FLOW, storage, tools.argparser.parse_args([]))

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)

  try:
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {'query':'SELECT TOP( title, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as revision_count FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE wp_namespace = 0;'}

    query_response = query_request.query(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
                                         body=query_data).execute()
    print 'Query Results:'
    for row in query_response['rows']:
      result_row = []
      for field in row['f']:
        result_row.append(field['v'])
      print ('\t').join(result_row)

  except HttpError as err:
    print 'Error:', pprint.pprint(err.content)

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ("Credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run"
           "the application to re-authorize")
```

As you see, just 30 lines, mostly concerned with getting and checking authorization and handling errors.  The "core" part, net of such considerations, is really just half those lines:

```
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
    query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
    query_data = {'query':'SELECT TOP( title, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as revision_count FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE wp_namespace = 0;'}

    query_response = query_request.query(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
                                         body=query_data).execute()
    print 'Query Results:'
    for row in query_response['rows']:
      result_row = []
      for field in row['f']:
        result_row.append(field['v'])
      print ('\t').join(result_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google data flow for python and if its a one time thing run it from your terminal or equivalent. alternately you can have a shell script in appenginecron that loops through code 52 times to get your data. google dataflow scheduling.